# What is the name for functions with this property similar to concavity?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, convex-analysis

What's the name of the class of functions satisfying the following property:

Given some convex space $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, a function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ is called $\mathbf{(?)}$ if for all $x_1,\dots,x_n \in D$ and values $t_1,\dots,t_n \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^n t_ix_i \in D$, we have that $\sum_{i = 1}^n t_if(x_i) \le f(\sum_{i = 1}^nt_ix_i)$.

This is basically concavity, but with the restriction $\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i = 1$ removed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call them *concave and homogeneous of degree $1$*.

Homogeneity of degree $1$ means that $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t>0$, as long as $x,tx\in D$. This property is implied by your definition, because on one hand, $tf(x)\le f(tx)$ while on the other (using $t^{-1}$ in place of $t$ and $tx$ in place of $x$), $t^{-1}f(tx)\le f(x)$.

Concavity is also implied by your definition, of course.

Conversely, suppose that $f$ is concave and homogeneous of degree $1$. Given $t_1,\dots,t_n>0$, let $T=\sum t_i$ and $s_i=t_i/T$. Then
$$\sum t_i f(x_i)= T\sum s_i f(x_i) \le T f\left(\sum s_i x_i\right) = f\left(\sum t_i x_i\right)$$

Comment: I guess this is good enough, homogeneity is a common enough concept. Thanks!